# Issues of install python from its distribution tar ball

Tags: python

I want to install Python2.7 from its tar ball distribution, Python-2.7.tgz, downloaded from the Python website.

My installation steps are as follow:

1. tar -zxvf Python-2.7.tgz
2. cd Python-2.7
3. ./configure --prefix=/opt/python-2.7 --enable-shared
4. make
5. make install
6. cp /opt/python-2.7/lib/libpython* /usr/lib64/

=========================

My purpose to install Python2.7 is to create a Python execution and runtime for somewhere else. So that I just need to copy the Python binaries and libraries to the places that I want to run Python2.7.

The question is when I run the Python2.7, it complains C header files are not found. Since I have copied the libraries, why it needs the header files?

---

```
[jet@localhost bin]$ ./python

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 549, in <module>
    main()

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 531, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 264, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 239, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 229, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 518, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 421, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)

  File "/home/jet/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 285, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)

IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /home/jet/python-2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
```

---

My goal is not to copy the *include* directory from the python installation directory to the places that I want to run python. Are there any complication or configuration options to achieve my purpose?

Comment: "for somewhere else" Where is this? Why don't you build Python there?

Comment: Isn't python's ```vitrualenv``` more proper solution for your case?

Comment: Why are you looking to copy only the libraries from the built Python into `/usr/lib64`? I can see only one of two things happening: you only have the libraries (which is pointless), or you've overwritten another installation's libraries with your own (possibly incompatible) libraries. (Why?)

Comment: @LutzHorn I want to build a VM image and copy the python into the VM image.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy No. I want build a VM image with the python execution environment.